# window message not received using python win32api

Tags: python, pywin32, spy++, window-messages

I am using win32 packages to send messages to a window. I manage to get the handle and apparently the message is sent as I get return value 0 from send [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD58b.png). however it has no action in the window, and [spyxx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYcdL.png) does not see the message on the specified handle.
my window has no child window and is class UnityWndClass. (I believe it uses a 64 bit process as it was not visible with spy++?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the IDE as admin made it work (the program also requires admin)